# Error when checking input: expected input_19 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1190, 200, 200)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dimension, conv-neural-network

I am new to CNN and I am not able to identify how to solve this problem.
In this code I am training a set of images to obtain mask from convolutional network.the images are grayscale with shape (200,200). I am not able to identify where I am making a mistake.Also everytime I run my code there is error at different inputs.Any help would be appreciated.

following is the log generated:

```
Creating training images...
Saving to .npy files done.
Creating test images...
Saving to .npy files done.
------------------------------
Loading and preprocessing train data...
------------------------------
------------------------------
Creating and compiling model...
------------------------------
C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/training.py:101: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(25, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", data_format="channels_last")`
  conv2 = Conv2D(25, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="th")(inputs)
C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/training.py:102: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(25, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", data_format="channels_first")`
  conv2 = Conv2D(25, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="th")(conv2)
C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/training.py:103: UserWarning: Update your `MaxPooling2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last")`
  pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="tf")(conv2)
C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/training.py:105: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(50, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", data_format="channels_first")`
  conv3 = Conv2D(50, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="th")(pool2)
C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/training.py:106: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(50, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", data_format="channels_first")`
  conv3 = Conv2D(50, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="th")(conv3)
C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/training.py:107: UserWarning: Update your `MaxPooling2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last")`
  pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),dim_ordering="tf")(conv3)
C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/training.py:109: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(100, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", data_format="channels_first")`
  conv4 = Conv2D(100, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="th")(pool3)
C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/training.py:110: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(100, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", data_format="channels_first")`
  conv4 = Conv2D(100, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="th")(conv4)
C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/training.py:111: UserWarning: Update your `MaxPooling2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last")`
  pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="tf")(conv4)
C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/training.py:113: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(200, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", data_format="channels_first")`
  conv5 = Conv2D(200, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="th")(pool4)
C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/training.py:114: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(200, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", data_format="channels_first")`
  conv5 = Conv2D(200, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="th")(conv5)
C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/training.py:116: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2DTranspose` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2DTranspose(200, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same", data_format="channels_first")`
  up6 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(200, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',dim_ordering="th")(conv5), conv4], axis=3)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-25-4b34507d9da0>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/training.py', wdir='C:/Users/Asus/Desktop')

  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/training.py", line 205, in <module>
    train_and_predict()

  File "C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/training.py", line 163, in train_and_predict
    model = get_unet()

  File "C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/training.py", line 116, in get_unet
    up6 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(200, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',dim_ordering="th")(conv5), conv4], axis=3)

  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\merge.py", line 641, in concatenate
    return Concatenate(axis=axis, **kwargs)(inputs)

  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 594, in __call__
    self.build(input_shapes)

  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\merge.py", line 354, in build
    'Got inputs shapes: %s' % (input_shape))

ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 200, 50, 50), (None, 100, 50, 25)]
```

Here is my code:

```
#load dataset
import h5py
h5f = h5py.File('liver_augmented_dataset.h5', 'r')
X = h5f['ct_scans'][:]
Y = h5f['seg_mask'][:]
h5f.close()

X_ax = X[1310:2500]
Y_ax = Y[1310:2500]

X_t=X[2501:2619]
Y_t=Y[2501:2619]

image_rows = 200
image_cols = 200


def get_unet():
    inputs = Input(shape=(img_rows, img_cols,1))
#    conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
#    conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
#    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(25, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="tf")(inputs)
    conv2 = Conv2D(25, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="tf")(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="tf")(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(50, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="tf")(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(50, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="tf")(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),dim_ordering="tf")(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(100, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="tf")(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(100, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="tf")(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="tf")(conv4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(200, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="tf")(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(200, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="tf")(conv5)

    up6 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(200, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',dim_ordering="tf")(conv5), conv4], axis=3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(100, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="tf")(up6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(100, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="tf")(conv6)

    up7 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(100, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',dim_ordering="tf")(conv6), conv3], axis=3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(50, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="tf")(up7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(50, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="tf")(conv7)

    up8 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(50, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',dim_ordering="tf")(conv7), conv2], axis=3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(25, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="tf")(up8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(25, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',dim_ordering="tf")(conv8)
#
#    up9 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv8), conv1], axis=3)
#    conv9 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up9)
#    conv9 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv9)

    conv10 = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(conv8)

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[conv10])

    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-5), loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=[dice_coef])

    return model
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to compile the model successfully.
I wasn't able to recreate the Concatenate error mentioned in the log.

The other you should check is the input you provide to model should be reshaped in 4 dimension as in the question you mentioned reshape error for (1190, 200, 200) ,you should convert it to (1190, 200, 200, 1) the '1' is for number of bands.

so basically you should add an extra dimension to your grey scale image and convert it to (img_rows,img_cols,bands)

Comment: on what kind of data you tested it?

Comment: Thank you for your help.So it worked using expand_dim.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same situation with grey images, a reshape on the images will solve it by adding the extra dimension for grey scale channel.

```
train_images_reshape = train_images.reshape(no_images_train, h,w,1)
test_images_reshape = test_images.reshape(no_images_test, h,w,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

keras will need an extra dimension to specify the channel

format  is (no_of_images, height, width, n_channels)
n_channels=1 for grey scaled images
=3 for RGB